# Linux find files given multiple characters or strings

Tags: linux, terminal, grep, ls

I want to find files containing strings for example, `report_`, `8495`, `str1` and with extension `.dat`. The directory has tons of file and I want to find files containing these strings in the filename. I am not checking inside contents of file, just filename. What is good way to do this?

Using  `ls *...*...*...*` works, but I am wondering is there any sophisticated way of doing this.

Comment: try `ls *{report_,8495,str1}*.dat` ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is one way of doing it but I wouldn't call it sophisticated. I would call it crafty and useful. I use search pattern quite a bit. It can also be done with regex expressions but it is somewhat confusing. Anyway, look at sample below:

```
 [jesse@localhost test]$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jesse jesse 0 Sep 12 12:33 file8495
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jesse jesse 0 Sep 12 12:52 file8495.dat
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jesse jesse 0 Sep 12 12:52 file8495.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jesse jesse 0 Sep 12 12:33 mikereport_2
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jesse jesse 0 Sep 12 12:52 mikereport_2.dat
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jesse jesse 0 Sep 12 12:52 mikereport_2.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jesse jesse 0 Sep 12 12:32 myreport_1
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jesse jesse 0 Sep 12 12:52 myreport_1.dat
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jesse jesse 0 Sep 12 12:52 myreport_1.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jesse jesse 0 Sep 12 12:36 mystr1
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jesse jesse 0 Sep 12 12:52 mystr1.dat
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jesse jesse 0 Sep 12 12:52 mystr1.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jesse jesse 0 Sep 12 12:35 test8495
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jesse jesse 0 Sep 12 12:52 test8495.dat
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jesse jesse 0 Sep 12 12:52 test8495.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jesse jesse 0 Sep 12 12:33 testreport_template
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jesse jesse 0 Sep 12 12:52 testreport_template.dat
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jesse jesse 0 Sep 12 12:52 testreport_template.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jesse jesse 0 Sep 12 12:36 thestr1test
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jesse jesse 0 Sep 12 12:52 thestr1test.dat
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jesse jesse 0 Sep 12 12:52 thestr1test.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jesse jesse 0 Sep 12 12:32 tonyreport_1
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jesse jesse 0 Sep 12 12:52 tonyreport_1.dat
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jesse jesse 0 Sep 12 12:52 tonyreport_1.txt
[jesse@localhost test]$ 
[jesse@localhost test]$ for pattern in report_ 8495 str1; do  echo "Searchng for pattern: $pattern"; find . -name "*${pattern}*.dat"; echo "-------"; done
Searchng for pattern: report_
./mikereport_2.dat
./tonyreport_1.dat
./testreport_template.dat
./myreport_1.dat
-------
Searchng for pattern: 8495
./file8495.dat
./test8495.dat
-------
Searchng for pattern: str1
./mystr1.dat
./thestr1test.dat
-------
[jesse@localhost test]$
```